# Prevent Multiple entries in array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this simple code for taking each product, finding the type, and making that a category to show up in my site.

```
public function get_categories()
{
    $products = $this->get_products();

    $categories = array();

    $i = '-1';

    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        $name = ucfirst(strtolower($this->ci->inflect->pluralize($product['type']))); 

        if(!in_array($name, $categories))
        {
            $i++;

            $categories[$i] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => strtolower($product['type']),
            );
        }
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Now, it was working just fine until I needed to pass the `type` along with the `name` so now I'm making a multi-dimensional array.

Now obviously the `name` is never in array `categories` because its inside another array in that one.

How can I detect if the `name` already exists in the arrays inside the array `categories`?

Comment: Why don't you use the `$name` as key of the array instead of some number? Would give you a one dimensional array and you always know if `$categories[$name]` is set or not

Comment: Wow, I've been working on this too long apparently... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try thiss
change `[$i]` to

```
$category[$name]
```

or

```
   $i++;

if(!in_array($name, $categories[$i]))
        {


            $categories[$i] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => strtolower($product['type']),
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories[$i] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => strtolower($product['type']),
            );
```

change to

```
$categories[$name] = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'type' => strtolower($product['type']),
            );
```

and add

```
foreach($categories as $key=>$val){
 $out[$i] = $categories[$key];
}
```

or array_unique 
or similar (stated below link)

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

but I'm not sure if I understood right path